# Error loading CSS, JS, and images on every page except for root page

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-config

Local dev environment loads first page of laravel site correctly, but any page after that is missing CSS, JS, and images. (non of them are loaded)

I am setting up a site on my local server that works on the live and staging sites. Their setup uses Apache, and mine uses Nginx with Homestead.

I can get the site to load the first page properly. When I navigate to other pages, the html loads, but none of the CSS, JS, or images load.

I have double checked all folders that i pulled the content correctly, and everything is present. (The first page loads properly)

When I view the console, this is the error message I recieve:

GET http://website.test/public/front/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

I see 18 of these error messages. all related to CSS, JS, and images.

I have been stuck on this for hours, and am pretty knew to server side technologies. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Caddy DZ's solution is great for Laravel as it generates a an absolute URL, but I think it's important for you to actually understand why this is happening so you don't get stuck on it again.

Imagine you are viewing your site from the URL below, and have two linked CSS resources:
https://example.com/product/101

```html
1) <link href="front/css/bootstrap.min.css">
2) <link href="/front/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The two links produce different results! You must use a leading `/` to indicate the site root or all resources will be relative to the current directory path `/product`.

```
1) https://example.com/product/front/css/bootstrap.min.css
2) https://example.com/front/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Alternatively, Laravel provides the `asset()` helper which will generate an absolute URL.

```html
<link href="{{ asset('front/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

// becomes an absolute URL
<link href="https://example.com/front/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: This answer helped me understand what was happening, and how to solve other problems I encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid linking to static assets via relative links.
So instead of

```html
<img src="images/photo.png">
<link href="front/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="front/js/app.js">
```

Use the `asset` helper to figure out a full url

```html
<img src="{{ asset('images/photo.png') }}">
<link href="{{ asset('front/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('front/js/app.js') }}">
```